# I'm getting the following error before performing employee search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

When i load my controller i'm getting this error in my homepage, but after performing search the error will disappear and search results will be displayed there.

This is my view page:

```
       <div id="toggle_tst">
       <div class="scroll">
       <?php
    // List up all results.

       echo "<table id='table'>";
       echo "<tbody>";
       echo "<thead>";
       echo "<tr><th>NAME</th><th>Pernor No</th><th>DESIGNATION ID</th> 
       </tr>";
       echo "</thead>"; 
       foreach ($results as $row)
         {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['pernor_no'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['designation_id'];
        echo "</td></tr>";
           }
        if (isset($_POST['data_rows'])) 
           {
        //if the page has been submitted, append the rows
        echo $_POST['data_rows'];
           }
        echo "</tbody>";   
        echo "</table>";
          ?>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Controller:

```
       public function execute_search()
         {
    // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');
        $data['query'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->viewother();   
        $data['query1'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->viewcatprice();   

         // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model- 
        >get_results($search_term);
         // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->load->view('JcMeetingExpense/jc_meeting_expense',$data);
        }
```

Comment: $results is not returning array so you are getting error. are you able to get results from controller?

Answer (score 3):

use isset before going to execute loop.

isset is the best practice if you are using in your code for variables and array.

For your solution : use below code

```
if(isset($results)){ 
// all code inside it...
```

}

Answer (score 3):

always use isset() for kind of same condition.

For more details : [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)!

use below code

```
if(isset($results)){ 
 // all code inside it...

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you haven't set the variable `results`. So simple solution is to add a `isset()` before foreach loop.

```php
if(isset($results)){
   foreach ($results as $row){
     .
     .
     .
     .
   }
}
```